# Note: test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: java, arraylist

Simple java program that has a ArrayList with few elements. On compiling I got the following error: Note: test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

```
import java.util.*;
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList obj = new ArrayList<>();
        obj.add("A");
        obj.add("B");
        obj.add("C");
        obj.add(1,"D");
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a warning and not an error message -- there's a difference. So, after receiving that warning, did you "Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details" as it suggested? You're doing something when declaring your ArrayList that, while not improper, isn't the best way. If you just do what the warning says, you'll get a better idea of what's going on. In the future, don't immediately give up and start asking for help. If you lack the curiosity and discipline to run down these kinds of issues on your own, you may find your chosen career highly unsatisfying.

Answer (score 0):

As @MarsAtomic said, in the comment, it's a warning, not an error.
After that, I'd want to help you understand why the compiler gives you that warning.

As the `ArrayList` is a class that uses generics, which allows the class to be a container that holds objects of the type you need, you are expected to specify a fixed type to be used, for example `ArrayList<String> myList = new Arraylist<>();` In the other hand, if you don't specify the type, the compiler will use the type `Object` and it's considered that your list will work with "raw" type of data missing all complier checks for type-safe.

I hope it helps you!